# Expressing the type of variadic functions in Idris

Tags: idris, variadic

In the book "*Type-Driven developement with Idris*" the author explains how to create variadic functions. He takes the example of a `adder` function that consumes a first parameter `n: Nat` and then *n + 1* integer parameters to be added. In order to declare this function the book introduces the dependent type `AdderType` so that one can write:

```haskell
adder: (numargs: Nat) -> (acc: Int) -> AdderType numargs
```

So far so good. But then the following definition of `AdderType` is proposed:

```haskell
AdderType : (numargs: Nat) -> Type
AdderType Z = Int
AdderType (S k) = (next: Int) -> AdderType k
```

At this point I'm lost. Line `AdderType Z = Int` makes sense but the *last one does not*. I would have thought that the expression `(next: Int) -> AdderType k` had kind `Int -> Type`, but *not* kind `Type`. Does Idris consider that any dependent type is *also* a type? If yes, does that also apply to type constructor? (That is to say: does a value of kind `Type -> Type` also have kind `Type` ?)

**Disclaimer**: I'm a beginner in type theory so my usage of technical terms like "kind" and "dependent type" might be inappropriate. Please correct me if this is the case.

Answer (score 4):

Eventually I understood my mistake so I'm answering my own question just in case someone else might be interested. I was confusing the **kind** of `(next: Int) -> AdderType k` (which is indeed **a** type) with the **value** of `(next: Int) -> AdderType k` (which is **the** type of all functions from type `Int` to type `AdderType k`). What is true is that all the defined types except `AdderType Z` are function types. But a function type is just a normal type anyway.

The way I could make sense of it was by imagining what would be the result if we could define each `AdderType k` individually. It would be the infinite list of following definitions:

```haskell
AdderType Z = Int
AdderType (S Z) = Int -> Int
AdderType (S (S Z)) = Int -> Int -> Int
AdderType (S (S (S Z))) = Int -> Int -> Int -> Int
…
```

It then became very obvious that each `AdderType k` is indeed just a normal type. Furthermore each newly defined type could be used inside the right hand side of the following line:

```haskell
AdderType Z = Int
AdderType (S Z) = Int -> AdderType Z
AdderType (S (S Z)) = Int -> AdderType (S Z)
AdderType (S (S (S Z))) = Int -> AdderType (S (S Z))
…
```

And at this point the infinite list of definitions (except the first) could be replaced by a single polymorphic definition.

```haskell
AdderType Z = Int
AdderType (S k) = Int -> AdderType k
```